# How to join strings in an object list

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

`', '.join(strings)` can be used to concatenate all strings in a list.

Now I have a list storing objects, and I'd like to join their names together. e.g.:

```
>>> a=[{'name': 'John', 'age': '21'},{'name': 'Mark', 'age': '25'}]
>>> a[0]['name'] + ', ' + a[1]['name']
'John, Mark'
```

Is there a simple way like `join()` above to do this?

Comment: `', '.join([x['name'] for x in a])` I doubt there's anything simpler.

Comment: `strings.join(', ')` is from JS, right?

Comment: @vaultah It would be simpler in some sense to remove the square brackets in your answer, and just use `','.join(x['name'] for x in a)`.

Comment: @RayToal brackets make the performance difference in case of `join`.

Comment: Thanks @vaultah, you should post it as an answer, even you might think it is simple :) Can you elaborate why it has performance difference?

Comment: Indeed the lists vs. generators will differ in performance. I was playing on "simpler" in terms of the number of characters in the solution and probably should have had a smiley. :)

Comment: @Deqing Please check my answer now, I included a link to another answer where the reason for the performance difference is discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have list of dictionaries not list of objects. We can join them together like this

```
print ", ".join(d["name"] for d in a)
```

`d["name"] for d in a` is called a generator expression, `str.join` will get the values from the generator expression one by one and join all of them with `,` in the middle.

But, if the list of dictionaries is too big then we can create a list of strings ourselves and pass it to the `str.join` like this

```
print ", ".join([d["name"] for d in a])
```

Here, `[d["name"] for d in a]` is called list comprehension, which iterates through `a` and creates a new list with all the `name`s and we pass that list to be joined with `,`.

---

I just noticed the discussion in the comments section. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/1903116) to know, why List Comprehension is better than GenExp in string joining.